# padStart() targetLength is not met

Tags: javascript, string

```js
const id = 46919;
const string = id.toString(36); // output: "107b"

console.log(string.padStart(3, '0'));
```

The expected output of the `console.log()` would be `107` since the targetLength of method padStart() is equal to `3`, but the actual output is `107b` which is a total of `4` characters.

Would you know why this happens please?

Edit: I misunderstood the use of this method, I thought it would cut the extra characters like slice()

Comment: The padStart() method pads the current string with another string (multiple times, if needed) until the resulting string reaches the given length. - MDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the toString(36) converts the number to base 36 from base 10, 46919 is 107b in base 36. padStart will add characters until the length is equal to the first parameter. Since 107b is already 4 characters it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `parseInt()` in the end of code

```
const id = 46919;
const string = id.toString(36);
console.log(parseInt(string.padStart(3, '0')));
//output 107
```